# Static BroadcastReceiver not working ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create a static broadcast receiver, but it is not working.
I'm using API level 25.

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.broadcastreceivertry">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
                android:name=".ScreenReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ScreenReceiver.java

```
package com.example.broadcastreceivertry;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("Screen Update", "Screen ON/OFF");
    }

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.broadcastreceivertry

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var SCREEN_INTENT = "Screen.Intent"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

After the code is running, it is not able to receive the broadcasts made by android system.

If I dynamically register these receivers in my MainActivity then there is no issue. But in this static registered receiver, I'm not able to get broadcast.

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a)

Comment: I'm using it on API 25 and not 26. So this might not be a problem.

Comment: @MeetMaheshwari check my answer then

Comment: @MD, I'm currently using Android 7.1.1 that is API 25 and still receiving the same Problem.

Comment: @Jasurbek, No your answer wasn't helpful. I'm using stock android on Android Emulator.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the
>   manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts
>   that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit
>   broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you
>   can use scheduled jobs instead.

That means if you really need broadcast receiver then you should dynamically register and unregister it by code

As @MD mentioned [this](https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a) URL illustrates why it is not allowed and how to deal with this issue.

**Android 7.0**

Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher don't send the following system broadcasts:

```
ACTION_NEW_PICTURE
ACTION_NEW_VIDEO
```

Also, apps targeting Android 7.0 and higher must register the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcast using

> registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)

. Declaring a receiver in the manifest doesn't work.

[Official site](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) will describe all changes in broadcast reciever